# manage.py throwing error "PostgreSQL with tsearch2 support is needed to use the pgsql FTS backend"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, windows-7

First off, the requisite "I'm quite new to python" comment must be made.

Some of my environment details:
- Windows 7
- Python 2.7
- Django 1.3.4
- PostgreSQL 9.2

I get the following error thrown when I attempting to run "manage.py syncdb".

```
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\fts\backends\pgsql.py", line 46, in __init__
    raise InvalidFtsBackendError("PostgreSQL with tsearch2 support is needed to use the pgsql FTS backend")
fts.backends.base.InvalidFtsBackendError: PostgreSQL with tsearch2 support is needed to use the pgsql FTS backend
```

I'm confused about why this error is being thrown because I have the Django-tsearch2 package installed (found here: https://github.com/hcarvalhoalves/django-tsearch2)

Any insight as to why I'm getting this error?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: +1 included your versions, OS, and exact error message without being asked. Since you're a new user doing the right thing I really wish I could +100 you instead ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use an older Django version with a newer PostgreSQL.

Full text search was converted from a contrib module into a built-in feature in more recent PostgreSQL versions. It used to be the `tsearch2` extension, which appears to be what Django is looking for.

For backward compatibility with older versions PostgreSQL still includes an extension that provides the old operators and syntax of `tsearch2`. You can enable it in a database by running, as a PostgreSQL superuser, the command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tsearch2;
```

This should allow your older Django version to "see" the full text search support.